# Setting StackOverflow like Permissions in Yahoo OAuth

Tags: oauth, yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

I could connect to the Yahoo OAuth from my website.
But I don't know how to access just the email and username of the end user.
Just like what Stack Overflow does when allowing logging in using Yahoo.

Which [Yahoo OAuth Permissions(Scopes)](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-scopes.html) does that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Stackoverflow uses OpenID for the login, not OAuth.
To get the email and name of the user from the OpenID Identity Provider (Yahoo in this case), there are two possible mechanisms:

- [Simple Registration](http://openid.net/specs/openid-simple-registration-extension-1_0.html)
- [Attribute Exchange](http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html)

By looking at the redirection URL, it seems that, with Yahoo at least, Stackoverflow uses Attribute Exchange and requests these attributes:

- http://schema.openid.net/namePerson
- http://schema.openid.net/contact/email
- http://axschema.org/namePerson
- http://axschema.org/contact/email

Comment: +1 Saw that while I was researching more. Couldn't explore more as more important work interfered. your answer sounds very logical.  will look into it when i get time.